# How to show date and time when viewing data in a JTable from a table in MySQL?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I Have a GUI that shows any table in a database by typing its name in a JTextArea, most of the tables have some datetime columns. When i override the getColumnClass method, the columns with datetime now will only show just the date. I could avoid overriding getColumnClass but I want to have the option to sort columns accroding to each column's type, which can only be achieved by overriding getColumnClass.

Comment: It's right there, in the official tutorial about JTables: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: What type are you returning from getColumnClass for those columns?  If you return `java.sql.Date.class`, you will only see date information.

Comment: Don't forget to post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem so we don't  have to guess what you may or may not be doing.